# create a Windows bootable USB stick with Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, windows

I am Linux user and currently there is no Windows* PC s available to me .
I just want to experience the Windows 8
I have a Windows 8 Image/files
I have a running Ubuntu PC
I have an 8 GB USB disk
I want to install Windows in a old PC which doesn't have support for UEFI boot.
Is there any solution available ?

Comment: Yes. But I don't have enough reputation to post the answer there

Comment: You could take a look at this method on ServerFault: [How to make Windows 7 USB flash install media from Linux?](http://serverfault.com/questions/6714/how-to-make-windows-7-usb-flash-install-media-from-linux). I have used it in the past to create Windows 8 and Windows 10 preview bootable USB-stick from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

In Non-UEFI machines, we can use GRUB2 to make USB stick bootable.
Then, we can use 'ntldr' command in the GRUB2 to boot Windows from USB.

- Enable the boot flag on the target partition of the USB. It can be easily done with the use of the tool called "GParted". It is a GUI tool for drive partitioning .
- If the installation image is a ISO file, Mount it and access the files.
- Copy the all files to root of USB drive
- Install GRUB to USB Drive.

  ```
  grub-install --target=i386-pc --boot-directory="/media/user/MyUSBDrive/boot" /dev/sdX
  ```
- Configure GRUB to boot Widows.

  Place the following file as "/boot/grub/grub.cfg" in the USB dirve

  ```
  set menu_color_normal=white/black
  set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
  menuentry 'Install Windows 8' {
   ntldr /bootmgr
  }
  ```

See complete answer at my blog
[Creating a bootable windows USB from Linux](http://harish2704.blogspot.in/2015/04/creating-bootable-windows-usb-from-linux.html)

Comment: Could you please include the essential parts from the blog post directly in your answer? It is better to include the information directly and leave the link as a source.

Comment: This is NOT the **recommended approach**, as using UEFI (secure boot) provides additional security to prevent many attacks to Windows (*a target of choice for malware/attackers*). *You may need to borrow use of a friends Windows PC, to create your install media.* **PS.** I have tried a method to create a UEFI install for *Windows 7 Pro*, but it did not work correctly (for reasons unknown).

Comment: @ david6 : In this case , Target PC is an old one. It doesn't have EUFI support. So UEFI, will not work.